# JTable Currency output and row next line

Tags: java, swing, jtable

please help me on this one guys.

- I need my table to convert floats into currency
- I want to get rid of the "......" at the end of the row 
  when it has a longer text.

I've tried things on the internet but it doesn't work.

```
public void GetDataFromListofTithes() throws SQLException
{
Connection connection = conn;
Statement state = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = state.executeQuery("select * from pogi;");
 ResultSetMetaData rsmetadata = rs.getMetaData();
 int columns = rsmetadata.getColumnCount();

 DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel()

         {
@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
    return false;
}};


 Vector<String> Columns_names = new Vector();
 Vector data_rows = new Vector();
 for(int i=1;i<= columns; i++){
 Columns_names.addElement(rsmetadata.getColumnName(i));
 }
 dtm.setColumnIdentifiers(Columns_names);

 while(rs.next()){
    int k = rs.getRow();
     data_rows = new Vector();
     for(int j = 1;j<=columns; j++){
    data_rows.addElement(rs.getString(j));

     }
     dtm.addRow(data_rows);}

}
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, and edge cases?

Comment: i cant seem to figure out how will i manipulate the rows fetched by rsmeta data from the mysql "select * from pogi" for my jtable display. cos i wanted the datas fetched to be converted as currency

Comment: Some [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A230513+%5Bjtable%5D+NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance).

Answer (score 1):

> i wanted the datas fetched to be converted as currency

Swing uses renderers to display data in a cell. So you need to create a custom renderer to display the number as a currency.

Check out [Table Format Renderers](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/11/table-format-renderers/) for an easy way to create custom renderers using a Formatter.

You can create your own, or use the custom classes provided in the link to simplify the task.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class MyTableCellRenderer extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer {
Font italic_11 = new Font("Tahoma",Font.PLAIN,10);
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00"); 
NumberFormat formatterwithcomma = new DecimalFormat("##,###,##0.00");
MessageFormat currformat = new MessageFormat("$###,##0.00");


    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            int rowIndex, int vColIndex) {

        setFont(italic_11);
// i need to make this code work but it has error saying cant convert object as number
        formatterwithcomma.format(value);
        setText(value.toString());
        return this;
    }

    public void validate() {}
    public void revalidate() {}
    protected void firePropertyChange(String propertyName, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {}
    public void firePropertyChange(String propertyName, boolean oldValue, boolean newValue) {}
}
```

Comment: im currently close to my needs man. thanks for recommendations and advices. i learned alot. but only one prob i have. i need to format object from cell renderer with numberformat or messageformat. i cant seem to make it work.

Comment: Why is your code so complex. I gave you simple examples to work from.

Comment: the code provided in the website dont seem to work in my case. maybe it doesnt work in defaultmodeltable idk.

Comment: The code I gave you works with all TableModels. The renderer has no idea what the TableModel is. All any TableModel does is store data. So you add a Double value to the model that contains the value. Then you use the renderer to format the double so that you add commas for the thousands and a decimal point for the cents. The classes I gave you where exactly used to take a "Format" object and then do the formatting.

Comment: (1-) There is absolutely no reason to implement all those methods when all you need to do is override a single method of the existing renderer. If fact using your code you lose normal rendering functions like display a border around the cell when it gains focus.

Comment: im using swing. does it count? ive tried it the way it is written and still get no result

Comment: im here to ask for help though sir cos im not really and honestly familiar of this kind of things yet in java.

Comment: When learning a new concept you need to simplify the problem. So your question as about display a number as a currency. So do that. Forget about the database. It is irrelevant where the data comes from. All you need is a DefaultTableModel that has Double values added to a column. Then you set the renderer for the column to be the currency renderer as I showed you how to do in my original answer. Then if you have a problem you have a simple [mcve] to post in the forum.

Comment: tnx sir camickr! i would love to check that out! appreciate it!